# Playwright with winston logger, How to Over write log file

Tags: logging, playwright, winston

I'm using Winston Logger in my playwright API automation scripts. How do I clear the log file before capturing the logs of each execution.
Below code is logging only the last script log, where as i executed more than one script.
When used "options: {flags: 'a'}" it is appending logs to the existing logs.
I want the file to display only the logs of all the scripts from latest execution.

export default class Loggerutility {

```
options = {
    level: "infor",
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
            level: "info",
        }),
        new winston.transports.File({
            filename: 'logs/performance.log',
            options: {flags: 'w'},
            level: 'info',
            maxsize: 5242880,
            maxFiles: 5,
        })
    ]
}

logger = winston.createLogger(this.options);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier way would be to remove the log file before you initiate your logger on each run. You can do this with the [fs.unlink](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-unlink-method/) or [fs.unlinkSync](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-unlinksync-method/) methods.